# Linux virtual machine for PHP/MySQL/JS Eclipse-based web development

Tags: gratis, linux, web-development, virtual-box

I am aware of the [Vee Dee Eyes](https://lifehacker.com/398848/veedee-eyes-offers-pre-configured-linux-distros-for-virtualbox) site, but that only seems to offer distros, empty of any but the default applications.

I am looking for a Virtual Machine for web development (and another for c/c++, but that's for another question) as follows:

**Must Have**

- gratis
- Linux VM image, for [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- MySql (or MariaDB) installed and configured
- Eclipse for PHP installed and configured, including Xdebug
- Eclipse for JS installed and configured, with a strong preference for Angulrjs

**Nice to have**

- distro is Ubuntu
- fixed size approx 30 to 40gB, but that's pushing the request a bit, so I will accept any size
- Chrome browser with useful add-ins (PHP console, Cross Origin Request, Local browser, storage, flush cache, etc)
- any other web developer tools

I have already spent two evenings configuring such a VM and have realized that lots of others must have configured this particular wheel before me.

Know you of such a beast?

Comment: I've made several for my students over the years.  Nothing in the past few months, and nothing with Eclipse (I did have Java, Netbeans, SceneBuilder, etc on one).  Really trivial to do, shouldn't take but a few hours not 2 evenings...

Comment: I know that I can do it manually, but was just wondering if there is a way to script it

Comment: Well, you didn't ask about scripting it, you asked about a ready-to-go VM image... Just for giggles I'm loading the last java one I did to check it for Eclipse - it may be there.  If so, how can I get it to you?

Comment: I asked about scripting it [on the relevant site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416072/can-i-programatically-create-a-ubuntu-distro) in such a way that there is not a duplicate question. If your distro fulfills my "must have"s, let me know  & we will find a way. Thanks (+1)

Comment: A year later, and I am no further forward :-(